# What is this anime where the girl wears a ribbon wrapping her hair like double helix and wears black dress?

Tags: elemental-gelade

I saw the trailer of this anime on the Bleach DVD Volume 1, which was featured in the Extras > Trailers. Other anime trailers that were featured on the DVD were for Black Cat, One Piece, Death Note, Eureka 7, Dragon Ball Z remastered and that's all I remember.

For the unknown anime trailer:

- The song sounded like j-techno with female singer. I could recalled an English part of the lyrics being "I need you, I just kiss you, in my life"
- Opening sequence shows a nude (?) girl in her early/mid teens with long pale blue hair tiptoed on the water
- The main character (?) is a boy in his early/mid teens with gold brown hair that is shaped like razors on the sides and wears red clothing

  [image: Hair colour of the boy (Maybe 1 or 2 shades darker)]
  (Image of hair colour, maybe 1 or 2 shades darker)
- The girl  wears a black dress and has a black/white ribbon wrapped around her hair, kind of like a double helix.

  [image: Appearance of the girl (REALLY SIMILAR ALMOST IDENTICAL)]
  **(Almost identical to the image of the girl in the trailer)**
- The main character and the girl seem to be romantically linked, as they are seen holding hands and the girl comforts the boy.
- Other characters in the trailer are shown one by one with small girl figures popping up behind them. Maybe the little girls are spirits or guardians?

That's all I have for the description, I've tried so long to find out what this anime is and I couldn't find anything related to it except for the picture of the girl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google reverse image search says [**Elemental Gelade**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1250/Elemental_Gelade), and the girl is called [Reverie Metherlence](http://myanimelist.net/character/2372/Reverie_Metherlence/pictures).

A brief description from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elemental_Gelade):

> The fantasy adventure is a tale of a group of five who are on a journey to Edel Garden, the birthplace of mystical beings called Edel Raids who are described as "living weapons".

Comment: Yes, but OP just uses these images as rough examples. (Or not?)

Comment: YES YES ELEMENTAL GELADE THANK YOU THANK YOU TSUGUMORI-704

Comment: I stand corrected, thought you would have checked the sources of your pictures first.